# Creating a matrix according to some rules

Tags: matlab, matrix

How can I generate the following matrix having `m` rows and `n` columns?

```
1st row      1   2   3   L   n-1 n
2nd          2   3   4   L   n   1
3rd          3   4   5   n-1 1   2
Nth          M   M   M  ....
N-1          m-1 m   m+1  L  m-3 m-2
last         m   m+1 m+2  l  m-2 m-1
```

Comment: Does this matrix have a name? Does it come from some algorithm? This could be very useful to your question.

Comment: What are `L` and `M`? Is `m > n`? You need to explain this more clearly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.

Comment: i don't know who is L and M, that was what the teacher said, to create that matrix, and yes, m>n

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to tell from your description, but it appears you want to create a matrix where the first row is `1:n` and each successive row is a circular shift to the left of the previous row. If so, you can still use [`hankel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html) for this (as Dev-iL mentions in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50821861/52738)), but incorporate a [remainder operation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rem.html) like so:

```
n = 5;
m = 8;
mat = rem(hankel(0:(m-1), (m-1):(m+n-2)), n)+1

mat =

     1     2     3     4     5
     2     3     4     5     1
     3     4     5     1     2
     4     5     1     2     3
     5     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4     5
     2     3     4     5     1
     3     4     5     1     2
```

Comment: You can do a similar thing with `toeplitz`. These two functions always seem to win out in these patterned matrix operations!

Comment: @Wolfie: Yeah, `toeplitz` is usually the go-to for diagonal pattern generation, `hankel` for anti-diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a [Hankel matrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html). You should use the 2-input syntax for it,

```
H = hankel(c,r)
```

So for example, with `m = 4` and `n = 5` we get:

```
m = 4; n = 5;
X = hankel( 1:m, m:m+n-1 )

X =

     1     2     3     4     5
     2     3     4     5     6
     3     4     5     6     7
     4     5     6     7     8
```